BMS-Battery System
I am facing an issue, I am building my circuit found below in the image, I am managing a battery pack using a BMS (link: https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/STM_4_19_2023_DB4989rev1b-3159205.pdf) (link for development board: https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/STM_4_19_2023_DB4989rev1b-3159205.pdf) where each battery cell is connected to the BMS and the whole Battery pack also is connected to BMS. The BMS then is connected to an STM32 to read data from it through signal lines. Now in order to build my system and to have a common ground between 3 sub systems I am connecting the B- of my battery to the GND of STM32. The problem is that two of the STM32 that I have used in this system had a short circuit between Vin and GND and are burnt down now and couldn't figure the issue. I am suspecting that the issue might be due to the common ground between Battery pack and STM32 knowing that I was always connecting my B- first to the STM32 then connecting the cells to the BMS to turn it on.
Any help please?



(edit) info from comments
B- is the negative terminal of my battery and it is not connected to the ground.
B- is connected to the GND of the BMS, so if I'd have to have a common GND between BMS and microcontroller then it is the same as the B- of the battery pack. That was the reason behind connecting the B- directly to STM32 in order to have a common reference for communication but my fault I guess was that I connected the B- at first to the GND of STM32. Before it was connected to power supply then I connected the battery to BMS and turned on my power supply.
The BMS should power the power board and then the power board must power up the STM32 but for simplicity I used a power supply instead of my power board. And to add the communication connector does not have a GND pin.
Power supply is used to power up the STM32, BMS is used to record the voltage values o the batteries only and print the data using STM32.
(/edit)

Is B- not tied to GND?

B- is the negative terminal of my battery and it is not connected to the ground

so then don't tie it to ground. Why would you want to do that?

@MarcusMüller , Shouldn't I have a common ground between my batteries, BMS, and STM32 ?

@MohamedSmaili why? I see why BMS and microcontroller need a common reference voltage for communication, but the battery might just be at any potential.

@MarcusMüller B- is connected to the GND of the BMS, so if I'd have to have a common GND between BMS and microcontroller then it is the same as the B- of the battery pack  that was the reason behind connecting the B- directly to STM32 in order to have a common reference for communication but my fault I guess was that I connected the B- at first to the GND of STM32 before it was connected to Power Supply then I connected the battery to BMS and turned on my power Supply

Show all the connections, grounds as well. Is there any connection between your PSU and the battery or BMS? Usually the BMS will be powering something, are there any of those connections you've not shown? It might be helpful to diagram all the batteries in your battery pack (as long as there are not too many)

@Neil_UK Further details were added to the schematics, the BMS should power the Power Board and then Power Board must power up the STM32 but for simplicity I used a Power Supply instead of my Power Board. And to add the communication connector does not have a GND pin.

@MohamedSmaili  "for simplicity I added something that can also bring another sets of additional potentials to my system". Nope, you made everything more complicated. And if something has a connector for communication with single-ended signals, that connector has to have a reference potential. No way around it. Please include the datasheet of your BMS, or at the very least a photo of the connector.

There's plenty of points on that BMS board where you can grab a ground connection. B- is not one of them. There's a current sensing shunt between B- and system ground. I mean, the GND pin is right next on the same connector as your WAKEUP, NSHIP, FAULTN…. Literally next to it!

I'm puzzled, what's the function of your circuit? Is the power supply to charge the battery on the left? Is the battery to back-up the power supply to the STM should it fail? I want to know where high currents are flowing, where high voltages are switching on and off, as well as the reference terminals for all logic signals.

@MarcusMüller a picture of my connector was added to the question.

@Neil_UK, power supply is used to power up the STM32, BMS is used to record the voltage values o the batteries only and print the data using STM32

I get that you misdesigned your connection, @MohamedSmaili. But the connector on the BMS has ground pins. You should use them. B- is not a ground pin, as said!

I tried to clear up your edit, including a 92 word sentence. Try standing up and say it loud in one breath.


B- is connected to the GND of the BMS

BMS ground should be connected to your MCU ground, directly, in parallel to the data lines. Chances are: a ground connector is already part of the data
By adding another conductor from MCU ground directly to battery, you made a second path for high current to get from the battery to the BMS (or the other direction), by going through the MCU board.
High currents in conductors lead to potential differences. And suddenly your MCU is at a different ground potential than the BMS, the IO pins conduct more current than they should, and your MCU burns.
You won nothing by adding this connection – for the small communication signals, sharing the ground between MCU and BMS was enough, and your MCU is absolutely not interested in being exposed to whatever happens to ground potential on the battery side.
Adding to this is the fact that the battery side is probably very noisy – yet another reason to not connect to that.

Totally agree with what you said, but to clarify things more, B- in my case is connected to the GND of the BMS so connecting GND of the BMS to the GND of STM32 isn't it the same as connecting a GND of the BMS to the B- of the batteries and then connecting B- to GND of STM32 ?

as I explained: no, it's not the same. Please re-read my answer! it explicitly addresses that. It's the main point.

I see your point but to clarify things more, I have added further details to my schematics if you can check it, the communication connector does not include a GND pin so I don't have a GND path from BMS directly to STM32, so I don't have two paths as you mentioned. Since I had a problem with not having a GND pin on communication connector, my assumption was that connecting B- to GND of BMS then connecting B- to the GND of STM32 would be the same as having a common GND for the whole system. Can you please re explain to me why they are not the same as you mentioned ?

you need a reference level from BMS to MCU, so you need to figure out where to get that from the BMS. Include the datasheet of your BMS in your question!

and I've explained why in my answer: potential difference. This is really just Ohm's law at work.

True I need a reference level from BMS to MCU so to have this reference level I connected B- to GND of BMS and then that same node was connected to GND of STM32 that was my assumption that this was the same node.

you need to stop thinking that you established a reference level with that. You did not. Just because there's a conductor from A to B doesn't mean A to B have the same potential. Conductors have resistance. Ohm's law applies.

Datasheet was added in my Question. I totally agree that there is a different conductivity I was simply using a jumper wire to connect to A to C, to have A and B and C connected.

did you read my comment under your question regarding that B- is not ground?

I added another picture showing how B- is connected to the GND of the BMS board in my question.

@MohamedSmaili you've crossed the point where I think that you're either intentionally ignoring what I said or I need to assume you just need to sit down and closely re-read all the things that you've been told so far to understand it. Your connections are wrong, you need to do them differently, and I've explained how and why. Either way, you're not listening to what people remark, so I think I'll leave you alone for a while.

I'd appreciate if you can have a look on the link added in the question for development board and check page 3 where it clearly shows how B- is connected to the GND. I appreciate your help.

Again, you ignore the things I wrote above. Can't help you when you don't try to understand what I wrote. You connecting to B- is wrong, no matter how many times you try to justify that.

I'll make the test, and I'll connect B- of the battery to the GND of the BMS board then connect the GND pin of the BMS in parallel with communication signals with STM32F756zg is that what you are suggesting then ? I'll make the test and get back to you.

to clarify things I am not ignoring what you have said and I totally agree with your point if you can check the question I was absolutely agreeing with the fact that B- cannot be connected to STM32F756zg but I was searching for a technical proof. Thank you.

what is the point of you saying you agree with me if you then insist on your approach that I clearly say is wrong? The "technical proof": see my answer. How many times do I need to repeat that you mustn't assume that just because two things are connected, they are at the same potential? I'm giving up here. You say "I agree", and then outright disagree.

@MarcusMüller The shunt resistor is not between B- and system ground, it is between B- (= system ground) and the charger (CH-).

@Jens exactly. So it's still a very bad idea to grab from B- at the battery side (see OP's drawing), because we have the ground shift due to current on the battery cable probably being substantial, and system ground, i.e., the ground that OP's "power supply" box connected to the MCU has might be different from what B- is by current times (cabling resistance + shunt resistance); which is worse than just shunt resistance. (Note that the shunt resistance is probable an order smaller than the resistance of cabling and connectors, if I'd have to infer from OP's description)

@MarcusMüller Yes, there are enough GND pins (9, 20, 32) on the connector to use..
